# Add an Image to a placeholder input type

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a login form, and I can't figure out how to put an image in with the placeholder. The current code I have is

```
            <span class="material-icons" style="font-size:20px; color: gray; float: left;">person
                <input placeholder="username" type="text">lock
            </span>

            <span class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: gray; float: left;">lock
                <input placeholder="Password" type="text">
            </span>
```

...But none of that has worked to do what I need.

I would like the image to be inside of the input, not in front of it.

Comment: couple of options: use pesudo elements ```material-icons::after``` or add in an ```img``` tag and position it absolutely

Answer (score 12):

**Try using this code**
It will show an image as a placeholder in the text field, and it will hide when you click on the text field.

```css
input#search {
    background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-2-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/search-512.png');
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: 20px;
    /* Extra Styling */
    padding: 5px 3px;
    transition:0.3s;
}
input#search:focus {
    background-image:none;
    text-indent:0px
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" Placeholder="Search" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the background property with class in your CSS.

```
       <html>
            <head>
            <title></title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        input.test{
           padding: .5em; 
        }
        input.icon[value="SEARCH WORDS"]{
            padding-left:48px; 
            background: 
url(https://material.io/icons/static/images/icons-180x180.png) no-repeat 8px center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="icon" value="NOT SEARCH WORDS">
    <input class="icon" value="SEARCH WORDS">
</body>
```

hope that helps