# How to add icon to autocomplete in PrimeVue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, primevue

I've run into this issue. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/2036) for this at the moment.
I've provided my workaround in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone looking for alternatives can either add a placeholder value to the Autocomplete with emojis as 'icons'

### Option 1

```js
<AutoComplete
  class="inputSearch"
  id="artist"
  v-model="selectedArtist"
  :suggestions="filteredArtists"
  @complete="searchArtist($event)"
  placeholder=" Search Artist"
>
</AutoComplete>
```

### Option 2 (better)

OR use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819704/add-an-image-to-a-placeholder-input-type) where you add icons as a background image and indent the text away from it. You can remove the focus from the example if you want to keep the icon.

If you have primeicons imported, you can put the path to your desired icon in the url section of background-image. Additionally, you can add

```css
background-size: 0.8em;
background-position: left;
```

under the input in the CSS with your desired values to position and size the icon.

Final CSS in my case looks like this:

```css
.inputSearch input {
  background-image: url("../../node_modules/primeicons/raw-svg/search.svg");
  background-size: 0.8em;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

If you inspect the Autocomplete in a browser, you'll see an input wrapped in a span. That's why this works. I may copy those icons to my public folder later on. Not ideal, but a workaround for now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to upvote/comment on the answer above - it inspired me to make a few tweaks in order to add an icon to PrimeVue's Autocomplete

Result: [Image of Autocomplete with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E3eZ.png)

I changed the `background-position` to be located at a more specific position. I also targeted the `p-autocomplete-input` class.

```css
.p-autocomplete-input {
  background-image: url("../../node_modules/primeicons/raw-svg/search.svg");
  background-size: 1.5em;
  background-position: left 10px top 17px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
    <AutoComplete
      type="text"
      v-model="searchQuery"
      @input="search"
      placeholder="Search for an Address"
      :scrollHeight="'300'"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another workaround which uses `PrimeVue's` inbuilt CSS class to add icon in a normal InputText.

```
<span class="p-input-icon-right">
    <AutoComplete placeholder="Search here..." loadingIcon=null></AutoComplete>
    <i class="pi pi-search" />
</span>
```

I am setting `loadingIcon` as null for this workaround to prevent icons overlapping.

Here is the output (my custom style attributes applied):

[image: Output Image]